# Unable to send email using MailGun Node API

Tags: node.js, mailgun

When trying to send a simple test message via mailgun using their Node api I don't get any errors, but I also am not receiving emails nor am I seeing any response in the mailgun logs.

Here is the code I am using ...

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXX', 
  domain: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXXXXX'
})

async function sendInvite() { 
  var email = process.argv[process.argv.length - 1]

  const data = {
    from: 'support@acme.com',
    to: email,
    subject: 'Welcome!',
    html: '<p>Welcome!</p><p>You are very special!</p>'
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    mailgun.messages().send(data, (error, body) => {
      if (error) {
        console.error(error)
        reject(error)
        return
      }
      console.log(`Invite sent to ${email}`)
      console.log(data)
      console.log(body)
      resolve();
    })
  })

}

sendInvite().then(() => console.log('Done')).catch((err) => console.error(err))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that the problem I had was in the format of the domain I was passing into mailgun.

Before I had the following :

```
const mailgun = require('mailgun-js')({
  apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXX', 
  domain: 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXXXXX'
})
```

The problem is that the value for `domain` should not include the `https://api.mailgun.net/v3/` portion of the URL.  Instead it should ONLY have your domain, e.g. `mail.mydomain.com`

Comment: This way Mailgun returns "Domain not found".

Answer (score 0):

Did you attach your credit card to `mailGun` account? Or if you just need to test your logic, in your account `settings` you should confirm any email address, which will get emails from `mailgun`

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mailgun-http-api-test-failure-status-free-accounts-are-for-test-purposes-only/